# Responsive square img (padding-bottom: 100%) not working on iOS?

Tags: css, css-grid, responsive-images, object-fit

I have a grid of "Related posts" in my blog and tried the `padding-bottom: 100%` trick to make the image of each post responsive square.

It works on desktop but on mobile iOS the height of the images stretches to 100% of the viewport. On Samsung phone works fine.

Where am I going wrong? 
I checked the `object-fit` property on *Caniuse* and it is largely supported. Tried on Safari, Chrome, Edge, and Firefox: same strange behavior.

Thanks in advance for your valuable help!

Here is the markup:

```
<!-- GRID CONTAINER -->
<div class="related-posts"> 

    <!-- IMAGE OF EACH GRID ITEM -->
    <a class="img-wrapper">
         <img src="/path/to/img">
    </a>

    ... <!-- OTHER GRID ITEMS -->

</div>
```

And the SASS:

```
.related-posts
   display: grid
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr))
   grid-gap: 1.5rem

.img-wrapper
   display: grid
   place-items: center
   &::before
     content: ""
     padding-top: 100%
     display: block
     grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2
   img
     width: 100%
     height: 100%
     object-fit: cover
     grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2
```

Comment: I tried setting the height of the `.img-wrapper` to 0 and, even though it fixes the 1:1 image ratio on mobile, I get all sorts of problems with margins.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the CSS and now it works.
Here's the code:

```
.img-wrapper
   position: relative
   display: block
   &::before
     content: ""
     padding-top: 100%
     display: block
   img
     position: absolute
     width: 100%
     height: 100%
     object-fit: cover
     top: 0
     left: 0
     bottom: 0
     margin: auto
```

It seems the problem was setting every grid item to `display: grid`